# ECL Client Tool Despray using dfuplus

Tags: hpcc-ecl

My colleagues and I have been exploring the ECL client tools, and we have been wondering if we can use the dfuplus command to despray dataset directly to our azure virtual machines? If this is possible, is there anything we need to do to set it up, like connecting our VM to HPCC? The documentation is not very clear. This will greatly help us in our workflow. Thank you in advance.

Haven't tried anything. The documentation is not clear enough and I don't want to touch systems.

Answer (score 1):

You can use DFUplus.exe to despray files to any IP that is visible to the box from which you run the program. The DFUplus.exe docs are in the Client Tools PDF, available here: https://hpccsystems.com/training/documentation/all/

I think your real question here is: are the firewalls between your machine with the DFUplus.exe and your azure VM configured to allow you to do that? But that is a question you need to discover yourself because it's unique only to your configuration.

I would start by trying to use DFUplus.exe to despray to a box that is known to be visible (just so you learn how to use it). Then try it to your azure VM -- if it works, you're GTG, and if it doesn't then you know you have firewall issues to resolve.